# Laravel how to REPLACE INTO local database table SELECT FROM external database table on different server?

Tags: php, mysql

My Laravel 8 project is using mainDB defined in .env file.  I also defined an second external database as extDB.

```
DB_HOST=server1
DB_DATABASE=mainDB
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=pswd

DB_EXT_HOST=server2
DB_EXT_DATABASE=extDB
DB_EXT_USERNAME=user
DB_EXT_PASSWORD=pswd
```

As well as in the config/database.php

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'mysql_external' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_EXT_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_EXT_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_EXT_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_EXT_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]
]
```

I can get data from extDB using the following code:

```
$db_ext = DB::connection('mysql_external');
$images = $db_ext->table('GW_xImages')->get();
```

But how can I execute such query to sync both tables which have different fields?

```
REPLACE INTO mainDB.images (id, created_at, updated_at, is_active, rating, title, caption, summary, location, subregion, region, country_id, gps, keywords, author, note, date, camera_body, camera_lens, camera_focal, camera_iso, camera_speed, camera_aperture) SELECT Image_ID, Date_Created, Date_Modified, Mark_Active, TotalStars, ImageTitle, Image, ImageNewTitle, Location, SubRegion, Region, Country_ID, LocationGPS, Keywords, Author, Note, Image_Date, Camera_Body, Camera_Lens, Camera_Focale, Camera_ISO, Camera_Speed, Camera_Aperture FROM extDB.GW_xImage WHERE Date_Modified > NOW();
```

Comment: This is something that could be configured for a single table using the [FEDERATED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) or [CONNECT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-external-table-types/) storage engine.  Another database approach would be to replicate the external database into the current server. Any Larvel approach would need to retrive all the data and then insert into `mainDB`

Comment: The process does not need to be fast.  Currently I am manually duplicating the whole table on to the local server in phpMyAdmin but this process takes too many steps.  I just want to write a script that does the job automatically everytime the extDB table has been updated (fortunately not everyday!).  How can I duplicate the extDB table to the local server from within Laravel?

Comment: I know you're focused on a Laravel solution, but saying `mysqldump --host .... --where  'Date_Modified > NOW()'  extDB GW_bxImage | mysql --host localhost --user forge forge` would do the act of copying in one step. Then just execute the `REPLACE INTO` with a local table.

Comment: Thank you @danblack.  This solution does not work in one step, confirmed by my web server specialist.  So I have first to dump in a file, then import the file into the local server.  Then run the third step replace into.  Can I run all 3 steps from Laravel?  And also I do I know that the first step is finished before starting the second step?